# Able to get the response but unable to display react

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm very new to react and I am required to convert latitude to longitude which the latitude and longitude get from firebase. So the problem is that I am able to console log the address. However, I am not being able to display

This is my construtor

```
this.getAddressFromLatLong = this.getAddressFromLatLong.bind(this)
```

This is the function that I wrote for the converting

```
getAddressFromLatLong(lat, long) 
{ Geocode.fromLatLng(lat, long).then( 
    response => { 
        const address = response.results[0].formatted_address; 
        console.log(address); 
        return address; 
    }, 
    error => { console.error(error); } 
)}
```

This is where I render the address

```
return ( 
    <tr key={atData.uid}> 
        <td>{atData.uid}</td> 
        <td>{atData.user}</td> 
        <td><TimeStamp time={atData.dateTime} format='full' /></td> 
        <td>{this.getAddressFromLatLong(atData.latitude, atData.longtitude)}</td> 
    </tr> 
)
```

Please advise >.<

Edit:

I realised that the code I posted is not enough so here's more information about my problems and the end product that I wanted

So I have this page that displays all the address and users when a user select a lock from the dropdown list which get from the firebase

This is how I did my dropdown list

```
componentWillMount() {
    const lockSelected = this.state.selectedLock
    console.log(lockSelected)
    // Calling the Lock List
    axios
        .get(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE + '/' + doGetLocklist() + '.json?auth=' + process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_SECRET)
        .then((response) => {
            // console.log("=== componentDidMount: axios - Lock List ===")
            this.setState({ locklistArray: response.data, loading: false })
        })
        .catch((err) => { })
}
renderDropdown() {
    return _.map(this.state.locklistArray, lockData => {
        return (
            <option value={lockData.uid}>{lockData.lockName}</option>
        )
    })
}
```

This is how I render out the dropdown

```
<FormControl componentClass="select" placeholder="select" onChange={this.detectOnChangeEvent}>
    <option value="">- Please Select a lock -</option>
    {this.renderDropdown()}
</FormControl>
```

After that, when the user selected a lock, it will run this detectOnChange func so that it will re-render the table with the lock data

```
detectOnChangeEvent(event) {
    this.setState({
        selectedLock: event.target.value,
    })
    this.fetchSelectedATData(event.target.value)
    this.forceUpdateHandler()
}

forceUpdateHandler() {
    this.forceUpdate();
};

fetchSelectedATData(atlist) {
    var lockSelected = atlist
    axios
        .get(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE + '/' + doGetAuditTrailList() + '/' + lockSelected + '.json?auth=' + process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_SECRET)
        .then((response) => {
            // console.log("=== componentDidMount: axios - User List ===")
            console.log(response.data)
            this.setState({ atArray: response.data, loading: false })
        })
        .catch((err) => { })

    this.renderATlistArray()
}

renderATlistArray() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
        return (<Loading />)
    } else {
        return _.map(this.state.atArray, atData => {
            return (
                <tr key={atData.uid}>
                    <td>{atData.uid}</td>
                    <td>{atData.user}</td>
                    <td><TimeStamp time={atData.dateTime} format='full' /></td>
                    <td>{this.getAddressFromLatLong(atData.latitude, atData.longtitude)}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }
}
```

So now, everything is working fine. I do know that this is not the proper way of doing things also. Just that I can't display onto my table when I am able to console log and it get the correct address back.

[Here's a screenshot of the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nOxj.png)

Hopefully, with all these added information, it will be better for you guys to understand the code!

Comment: what is atData?please rovide more code

Comment: Consider adding Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problems so you will get much better answers

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code you posted

1. As written, `getAddressFromLatLong()` doesn't have a useful return value. It returns `undefined` because it's written using `methodName() {}` syntax without a return statement.

   Here's how to rewrite it so that it returns a value:

   ```
   getAddressFromLatLong (lat, long) { 
     return Geocode.fromLatLng(lat, long).then( 
       response => { 
         const address = response.results[0].formatted_address; 
         console.log(address); 
         return address; 
       }, 
       error => { console.error(error); } 
     )
   }
   ```
2. `getAddressFromLatLong()` calls an **asynchronous function** that returns a Promise. An asynchronous function doesn't produce a value immediately -- instead, we provide a **callback** that is eventually called (at some unknown point in the future) when the asynchronous function eventually produces a value.

   A callback is just a plain ol function that gets invoked **at some point in the future** with the result of an asynchronous operation.

   A **Promise** is a way to represent an asynchronous operation and register callbacks depending on whether the operation succeeds or fails.

   The `.then()` function allows us to register those success and failure handlers. The first function passed to `.then()` is called if the operation succeeds. The second function is called if the operation fails.

   There are other ways to register handlers on Promises: check out the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for the complete API.

In order to get this code working, we need start the asynchronous operation and then render the component after the data is available.

There are many ways to handle this, but the simplest is to **store the result of the operation in the component's state**.

Here's one way to rewrite this component so that it renders the asynchronously retrieved data when it's available:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  // This function gets called the first time the component is added to the DOM.
  // If the latitude or longitude changes, you'll need to call this function from the componentDidUpdate() lifecycle method.
  componentDidMount () {
    // Obtain atData, probably from props
    const atData = this.props.atData
    getAddressFromLatLong(atData.latitude, atData.longitude)

      // Update the component state with the address
      // setState() will trigger a re-render
      .then(
        address => this.setState({ address: address }),

        // If the Geocode() call fails, this function gets called.
        // As written, this component will continue to show a loading message if Geocode() fails, which isn't great UX.
        // You may want to add the error message to the state and display an error if the Geocode() fails.
        error => console.log('Error retrieving address', error)
      )
  }

  getAddressFromLatLong (lat, long) { 
    return Geocode.fromLatLng(lat, long).then( 
      response => { 
        const address = response.results[0].formatted_address;
        return address; 
      }
    )
  }

  render () {
    // Get atData, probably from props
    const atData = this.props.atData

    // The address is stored in the component state.
    // We'll show a loading message while we're waiting for the data.
    const address = this.state.address

    return ( 
      <tr key={atData.uid}> 
        <td>{atData.uid}</td> 
        <td>{atData.user}</td> 
        <td><TimeStamp time={atData.dateTime} format='full' /></td> 
        <td>{ address || 'Loading address...' }</td> 
      </tr> 
    )
  } 
}
```

You can improve this example code in a number of ways

- Render an error message if `Geocode` fails
- Render a loading spinner (instead of the `<tr>`) while waiting for the `Geocode` to finish
- Perform the `Geocode` from the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method so that we'll update the address whenever the latitude or longitude changes
- Retry the `Geocode` if it fails